# Python 'with' statement - how to tell what module/object/class supports it?

Tags: python

Raymond Hettinger surprised quite a few people when he showed slides 36 and 37. https://speakerdeck.com/pyconslides/transforming-code-into-beautiful-idiomatic-python-by-raymond-hettinger -- Many people knew that the with statement could be used for opening files, but not these new things. Looking at python 3.3 docs on threading, only at the very bottom, section 16.2.8, is it even mentioned.  From the lecture it was implied that using the 'with' operator was best practice.

- How is one supposed to figure out if 'with' is supported, what it can be tied to, etc?
- Also, how should 'with' be referred to? (threading with statement, python threading lock with statement,...), what is the vernacular to search and see if 'with' is supported (we can ask if something is iterable, do we ask if it's 'withable')?

ref:

- http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with 7.5
- http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers 3.4.10
- http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/threading.html 16.2.8

Comment: "...if with is supported...": Look for context managers. If it has an \__enter__ and \__exit__ method, the with statement is supported for that object.

Comment: "help(with) comes back with a syntax error". Try surrounding the term in quotes: `help("with")`

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that Raymond Hettinger presented something in 2013 that's non-3.x friendly but is 2.3-friendly (e.g., using `cmp` instead of `key` for sorting).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you don't ask if something is "withable", you ask if it's a "context manager".*

For example, in the docs you linked (which are from 3.1, not 3.3, by the way):

> Currently, `Lock`, `RLock`, `Condition`, `Semaphore`, and `BoundedSemaphore` objects may be used as `with` statement context managers.

Meanwhile, if you want to search in the interactive interpreter, there are two obvious things to do:

```
if hasattr(x, '__exit__'):
    print('x is a context manager')

try:
    with x:
        pass
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    print('x is a context manager')
```

Meanwhile:

> `help(open)` … makes no mention of it

Well, yeah, because `open` isn't a context manager, it's a function that happens to return something that is a context manager. In 3.3, it can return a variety of different things depending on its parameters; in 2.7, it only returns one thing (a `file`), but `help` tells you exactly what it returns, and you can then use `help` on whichever one is appropriate for your use case, or just look at its attributes, to see that it defines `__exit__`.

At any rate, realistically, just remember that EAFTP applies to debugging and prototyping as well as to your final code. Try writing something with a `with` statement first. If the expression you're trying to use as a context manager isn't one, you'll get an exception as soon as you try to run that code, which is pretty easy to debug. (It will generally be an `AttributeError` about the lack of `__exit__`, but even if it isn't, the fact that the traceback says it's from your `with` line ought to tell you the problem.) And if you have an object that seems like it *should* be usable as a context manager, and isn't, you might want to consider filing a bug/bringing it up on the mailing lists/etc. (There are some classes in the stdlib that weren't context managers until someone complained.)

One last thing: If you're using a type that has a `close` method, but isn't a context manager, just use `contextlib.closing` around it:

```
with closing(legacy_file_like_object):
```

… or

```
with closing(legacy_file_like_object_producer()) as f:
```

In fact, you should really look at everything in [`contextlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html). `@contextmanager` is very nifty, and `nested` is handy if you need to backport 2.7/3.x code to 2.5, and, while `closing` is trivial to write (if you have `@contextmanager`), using the stdlib function makes your intentions clear.

---

* Actually, there was a bit of a debate about the naming, and it recurs every so often on the mailing lists. But the docs and `help('with')` both give a nearly-precise definition, the "context manager" is the result of evaluating the "context expression". So, in `with foo(bar) as baz, qux as quux:`, `foo(bar)` and `qux` are both context managers. (Or maybe in some way the two of them make up a single context manager.)

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't been clear on how it was different between open and lock, but that makes sense, given the 'as' keyword used when using open.

Comment: @pyInTheSky: Well, the result of evaluating `open(path)` and the result of evaluating `lock` are both context managers, it's just that in the former case you're evaluating a function call, while in the latter case you're just evaluating an object. (You can say `with lock as other_name_for_lock:` if you really want to…)

Comment: Thanks for the extras, did not know about contextlib.

Comment: I found this good answer because I searched the web for "withable".  I'm glad that someone else also called it "withable", too!  "withable" is easily guessed.  "Context manager" is not as easy to guess as "withable".  I hope that writing withable many times in this comment about withable will cause Google searches for the word "withable" to find this good answer about python withable.

Answer (score 3):

afaik any class/object that  that implements `__exit__` method (you may also need to implement `__enter__`)

```
>>>dir(file)
#notice it includes __enter__ and __exit__
```

so

```
def supportsWith(some_ob):
   if "__exit__" in dir(some_ob): #could justas easily used hasattr
       return True
```

Answer (score 3):

Objects that work with Python's `with` statement are called *context managers*. In typically Pythonic fashion, whether an object is a context manager depends only on whether you can do "context manager-y" things with it. (This strategy is called [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).)

So what constitutes "context manager-y" behavior? There are exactly two things: (1) doing some standard set-up on entering a `with` block, and (2) doing some standard "tear-down", and maybe also some damage control if things go awry, before exiting the block. That's it.

The details are provided in [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), which introduced the `with` statement, and in the documentation you linked in the question.

### A `with` block, step by step

But let's run through this step by step.

To start, we need a "context manager". That's any object that provides set-up and tear-down behavior encapsulated in methods respectively called `__enter__` and `__exit__`. If an object provides these methods, it qualifies as a context manager, albeit possibly a poor one if the methods don't do sensible things.

So what happens behind the scenes when the interpreter sees a `with` block? First, the interpreter looks for `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods on the object provided after the `with` statement. If the methods don't exist, then we don't have a context manager, so the interpreter throws an exception.

But if the methods do exist, all is well. We have our context manager, so we move into the block. The interpreter then executes the context manager's  `__enter__` method and assigns the result to the variable that follows the `as` statement (if there is one, otherwise the result is thrown away). Next, the body of the `with` block is executed. When that's done, the context manager's `__exit__` statement is passed a (possibly empty) dictionary of information about any exceptions that occurred while executing the bock's body, and the `__exit__` method is executed to clean things up.

Here's a line-by-line walk-through:

```
with man as x:         # 1) Look for `man.__enter__` and `man.__exit__`, then ...
                       # 2) Execute `x = man.__enter__()`, then ...
    do_something(x)    # 3) Execute the code in the body of the block, ...
                       # 4) If something blows up, note it (in `err`), ...
                       # 5) Last, this (always!) happens: `man.__exit__(**err)`.
carry_on()
```

And that's that.

### What's the point?

The only subtlety here is that the context manager's `__exit__` method is *always* executed, even if an uncaught exception is thrown in the body of the `with` block. In that case, the exception information is passed to the `__exit__` method (in a dictionary I called `err` in the example above), which should use that information to provide damage control.

So a `with` block is just an abstraction that lets us shunt off set-up, tear-down, and damage-control code (i.e., "context management") into a couple of methods, which can then be called behind the scenes. This both encourages us to factor out boilerplate and provides more concise, readable code that highlights the core control flow and hides implementation details.